# php infinite loop and comet?

Tags: php, comet, infinite-loop

Something seems wrong with my php script, but I have no idea what it is. The only possible thing that seems to be wrong is something to do with the cache, but I am not sure. Here's my script, I'll tell you what's happened below the code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
header('Content-Type:text/event-stream');
$prevmod=$lastmod=filemtime('chattext.txt');
function waitformod(){
global $lastmod;
global $prevmod;
while($prevmod==$lastmod){
    usleep(100000);
    clearstatcache();
    $lastmod=filemtime('chattext.txt');
    }
echo 'data:'.file_get_contents('chattext.txt').PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
flush();
$prevmod=$lastmod;
}
while(true){
waitformod();
}
?>
```

This is supposed to be used with the JavaScript EventSource and send the contents of chattext.txt whenever it is modified. The file does not output anything, however. I think it is because of the infinite loop. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This happens: 1) I modify the file 2) The php file sends chattext.txt as it was before I modified the file. Does that make more sense?

Comment: You mean a part from the fact that you are using `global`s?

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work better?

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
header('Content-Type:text/event-stream');

$prevmod = $lastmod = filemtime('chattext.txt');

function waitformod(){
    global $lastmod;
    global $prevmod;

    while($prevmod == $lastmod) {
        usleep(100000);
        clearstatcache();
        $lastmod = filemtime('chattext.txt');
    }

    echo 'data:'.file_get_contents('chattext.txt').PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
    flush();

    $prevmod = $lastmod;
}

while(1) {
    waitformod();
}
```

Your current code looks like it reads the file, outputs it, waits for it to change, and then terminates.

Comment: This seems great! Just asking (it's not important) what does flush() do in this case? I've heard of it but don't know what it does.

Comment: It (tries) to force the server to flush the output buffer and send all data to the client at that time.  Output is often buffered and doesn't get send immediately.

Comment: It looked like this would work, but it doesn't output anything. I think it is the infinite loop. How can I fix this?